# How to compose a curl request correctly for wso2 api manager

Tags: api, curl, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Description:
I have configured an API (http://localhost:8280/GPNAPI2/1.0.0) that has Production and Sandbox endpoints (http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/iFaxWebService.asmx). All I need is to send a curl request to http://localhost: 8280/GPNAPI2/1.0.0, but receive a response from http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/iFaxWebService.asmx. As I understand it, wso2 am is needed for this, so that several external APIs can be connected to one gateway. I also created a subscription for http://localhost:8280/GPNAPI2/1.0.0.

Steps to reproduce:
I pass a GET request to http://localhost:8280/GPNAPI2/1.0.0 and pass a security token in the request, for example:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8280/GPNAPI2/1.0.0" -H "accept: */ *" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5EY3hOR1l3WW1NNBelpUQTR"
```

Everything is going well. But I don't know how to transfer data to the endpoint in one request: http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/iFaxWebService.asmx
A request of this type:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -i -X ​​--location --request POST 'http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/iFaxWebService.asmx'
--header 'Content-Type: text / xml'
--header 'SOAPAction: http://interfax.ru/ifax/Authmethod'
--data '
<soap: Envelope xmlns: xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns: xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns: soap = "http : //schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ ">
<soap: Body>

******
*****

</ soap: Body>
</ soap: Envelope> '
```

I want to understand how to combine these two requests into one, and whether it needs to be done. After all, my task, when accessing http://localhost: 8280/GPNAPI2/1.0.0, is actually working with http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/iFaxWebService.asmx

Affected Product Version:
wso2 apim 3.2.0 (We need this particular version, since the customer is using it and, for reasons I do not understand, does not want to switch to version 4.0.0).

Environment details (with versions):
windows 8

Please help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/tutorials/expose-a-soap-service-as-a-rest-api/#expose-a-soap-service-as-a-rest-api) to expose your SOAP service as a REST API using API Manager 3.2.0.

Basically, you have to provide your WSDL url in the first step (for example, `http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/iFaxWebService.asmx?wsdl`) and then continue as mentioned in the documentation.

If you go to the Resources section in Publisher portal, you'll be able to see  `SOAPAction` header and `SOAPRequest` body parameters are defined. Also, under the WSDL Definition section in the Publisher you'll be able to see the complete WSDL definition of your SOAP service. If you follow rest of the steps you'll be able to invoke the API by providing necessary header and body parameters through APIM devloper portal.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything worked out! Please tell me the following. I have configured active directory (LDAP) as the user store, how do I configure authentication when accessing the API? I mean, how can I change token authentication to LDAP authentication now?

Comment: The latest query on LDAP configuration for token authentication is completely a new concern that should be moved to a new question to get more attention and answers.